# calculations errors in a pizza game

Tags: java

i have to do a pizza game  ... i wrote all the code already .. it seems to work right most of it . the thing is that my numbers don't came out as they suppose to ... i know my error is in when i calculate the the cheesy crust.... can someone please help!

If the customer chooses to add cheesy crust (to anything but thin & crispy), then add the following to the basic price of the pizza:

```
k = ec

where:
    k = total cost of cheesy crust (dollars)
    e = size of pizza crust (inches)
    c = cost of materials (dollars per square inch - 0.02)
```

The size of the pizza crust is a measure of the pizza border:

```
for round pizzas:   e =  2π(d/2)    (the circumference)
for rectangular pizzas: e =  2(L+w) (the perimeter)

where
    e = size of pizza crust (inches)
    d = diameter of round pizza (inches)
    L = length of rectangular pizza (inches)
    w = width of rectangular pizza (inches)






enter code here
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pizza {

    /*
     * calculates price including tax
     * @return double
     */
   public static double calculatePriceWithTax(double price){

      return price * (1 + 0.07);
   }
    /*
     * calculates delivery fee if any
     * @return double
     */
   public static double deliveryFee(double price){
      if(price < 10){
         return 3;
      }

      else if(price >= 10 && price <= 20){
         return 2;
      }

      else if(price >= 20 && price <= 30){
         return 1;
      }

      else{
         return 0;
      }
   }

    /*
     * calculates basic pricing for total number of pizza
     * @return double
     */
   public static double calculateCost(int shape, int diameter, int length, int width, int numToppings, int typeDough){

      double a = area(shape, diameter, length, width);
      double v = volume(a, typeDough);
      double cost = a * (0.036  + numToppings * 0.025 ) + v * 0.019;
      return cost;
   }

    /*
     * calculates area of a pizza
     * @return double
     */
   public static double area(int shape, int diameter, int length, int width){

      double a = 0.0;

      if(shape == 1){ // round pizza
         a = Math.PI * (diameter / 2) * (diameter / 2);
      }

      else if(shape == 2){ // rectangular pizza
         a = length * width;
      }

      return a;
   }

    /*
     * calculates volume of a pizza
     * @return double
     */
   public static double volume(double a, int typeDough){

      double height = 0.0;

      switch(typeDough){

         case 1:
            height = 0.1;
            break;

         case 2:
            height = 0.25;
            break;

         case 3:
            height = 0.5;
            break;

         case 4:
            height = 0.9;
            break;
      }

      return a * height;
   }

    /*
     * calculates cost for cheesy crust
     * @return double
     */
   public static double calculateChessyCrustCost(int shape, int diameter, int length, int width){
      return size(shape, diameter, length, width) * 0.02;
   }



    /*
     * calculates size of pizza
     * @return double
     */
   public static double size(int shape, int diameter, int length, int width){
      if(shape == 1){ // round pizza
         return 2 * Math.PI * (diameter / 2);
      }

      else{ // rectangular pizza
         return 2 * (length + width);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      int shape; // 1 => round, 2 => rectangular
      int length = 0;
      int width = 0;
      int diameter = 0;
      int numToppings = 0; // number of toppings
      int typeDough; // 1 => thin & crusty, 2 => hand tossed, 3 => pan, 4 => texas toast
      boolean cheesyCrust = false; // true => add, false => don't add
      int lengthCrust = 0;
      int numPizza; // number of pizzas ordered
      int orderType; // 1 => delivery, 2 => take-out

      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("This program helps you to order pizza based on your personal preferences.");
      System.out.println("It notes your choices and calculates total cost for you, including tax and even delivery fee if applicable.");
      System.out.println("Please fill out information for the following:");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Pizza style:");
      System.out.println("1. Round Pizza");
      System.out.println("2. Rectangular Pizza");




      shape = scanner.nextInt();

      if(shape == 1){
         System.out.println("Diameter:(inches)");
         diameter = scanner.nextInt();
      }

      else if(shape == 2){
         System.out.println("Length:(inches)");
         length = scanner.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Width:(inches)");
         width = scanner.nextInt();}
      else {throw new IllegalArgumentException("Enter enter 1 fo Round pizza or 2 for rectangualar pizza"); 
      }

      System.out.println("Number of toppings:");
      numToppings = scanner.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Type of dough:");
      System.out.println("1. Thin & Crusty");
      System.out.println("2. Classic Hand Tossed");
      System.out.println("3. Pan");
      System.out.println("4. Texas Toast");
      typeDough = scanner.nextInt();

      if(typeDough != 1){
         System.out.println("Do you want to add cheest crust?[true/false]");
         cheesyCrust = scanner.nextBoolean();


      }

      System.out.println("How many pizzas do you want to order?");
      numPizza = scanner.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Select your receival method:");
      System.out.println("1. Delivery");
      System.out.println("2. Take away");
      orderType = scanner.nextInt();

      double a = area(shape, diameter, length, width);
      double v = volume(a, typeDough);
      double baseCost = calculateCost(shape, diameter, length, width, numToppings, typeDough);
      double crustCost = 0.0;

      if(cheesyCrust == true){
         crustCost = calculateChessyCrustCost(shape, diameter, lengthCrust, width);
      }

      double costOne = calculatePriceWithTax(baseCost + crustCost);
      double deliveryCharge = 0.0;

      if(orderType == 1){ // delivery
         costOne += deliveryFee(costOne);
      }

      double totalCost = deliveryFee(costOne * numPizza) + (costOne * numPizza);

      System.out.print("Area: ");
      System.out.printf("%.2f", a);
      System.out.print(" (inches square)");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("Volume:");
      System.out.printf("%.2f", v);
      System.out.print(" (cubic inches)"); 
      System.out.println(); 
      System.out.print("Base Cost: ");
      System.out.printf("%.2f", baseCost);
      System.out.print(" dollar"); 
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("Cost for one pizza: ");
      System.out.printf("%.2f", costOne);
      System.out.print(" dollar"); 
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("Your order has been processed. Total cost including taxes: ");
      System.out.printf("%.2f", totalCost );
      System.out.print(" dollars"); 
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Thank you for using our service.");
   }
}
```

Comment: `a = Math.PI * (diameter / 2) * (diameter / 2);` You're performing integer division here.

Comment: is actually giving me the right calculation for the area !my problem is in the cheesy crust!

Comment: If you're doing `a = Math.PI * (diameter / 2) * (diameter / 2);` with `diameter = 1` (per example), it will give you 0. So not sure if it's doing the right calculation.

Comment: I'm with them. Your `size()` method can't possibly be returning a correct value, and that is a large part of your crust cost calculation.

Comment: i just fix that.. still dons't work !

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1 is in your `area` method:

```
a = Math.PI * (diameter / 2) * (diameter / 2);
```

in java, `int / int = int`, so you have to cast it to double.

to fix this, try the following:

```
a = Math.PI * (diameter / 2.0d) * (diameter / 2.0d);
```

The same problem is in your `size` method. It should look like this:

```
return 2 * Math.PI * (diameter / 2.0d);
```

Comment: I think `2.0` would suffice.